# How to change default creator in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

My problem is that when I try to save a Simulink model, it gives the error message, that some characters in the model can not be encoded using Windows-1250. It also specifies the line number and byte offset, in which the invalid character is, which happens to be the "Creator:" line, and the invalid character is in my name. It's the character "á". I tried to find a solution using google and the matlab help, but found no way to change the name of the author.

Thanks!

Edit: Changing my name in the model properties doesn't help, the last modified by line still contains my original name.

Comment: change how your name is written in the computer... Thats a general problem in computers, names with ç,à,á,ä,Ñ,..... My advice: accpet that computers will never love you('r name). :D